# remove activity from stack

Tags: android, android-activity

I am developing an application in android. I am new in android.
In my application I have a category selection activity from that user have to check a check-box, based on that he will get view on another screen. I have a menu button in 3rd screen in that I have a button for selecting category, when I click on that button its also works fine but when I click back button it will redirect me 2 times at same activity... How to remove this problem? I have used `finish()` method but its also creates problem its get's me out from the application directly...
I want redirect to selection activity and it should not show me 2 times when I click back button ....

Is there any way please redirect me thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a call to `finish()` should work so you schould check your code for multiple calling the wrong method or something like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, activityClass.class);
activity.startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

you should also take a look at the `Intent` flags:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't clear enough for me to know if this will solve your problem, but if you include the following attributes on your `Activity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`, the so-attributed `Activity` will never appear in your history list.

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
         android:noHistory="true"
```

As for removing something from the history, I'm not sure how to do that, but I'm interested in the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You should call finish before you call Intent and go to next activity. so the current task is finished and will not be saved in stack and then you intent activity will come on top of stack. If you directly want to go to Selection activity, override onBackPressed() and intent to the activity you want to go to.

Answer (score 0):

There are different flags that you can use to control how your activity interacts with the activity history stack. Two that might be of interest to you are [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) and [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY).